# Xcode Provisioning Profile certificate error for iOS App Development

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

I am building an iOS app and I have done the following things in the web-based Apple Developer console:

- Created an app and App ID + Bundle ID for it
- Created a CSR, and then used that CSR to generate a Certificate for it
- Created a Provisioning Profile (referencing that Certificate) for it and downloaded the profile

I then open my app in Xcode and have tried importing that Provisioning Profile off the **Signing & Capabilities** tab, however I am getting an unexpected error:

[image]

**Does anybody know why I am seeing this *Provisioning profile* warning/error, and what I can do to fix it so that I am able to build/codesign/archive it?** I plan on manually uploading the archive to Test Flight so I can give my small list of beta testers an early-access preview for it.

**Please note:** I want to use manual codesigning, *not* automated.

#### Update

After following one of the recommended suggestions, when I open my downloaded Profile in Xcode I am presented with this error:

[image]

Interestingly enough, when I go to the Apple Developer console and look at all of my Certificates, none of them are named "*Apple Distribution:  Holdings LLC*", so I'm not sure why Xcode thinks a certificate with that name should be embedded inside of the profile.

Comment: Can you share your keychain certificate for this xxx Holdings LLC owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** [First Create the CSR file](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/create-certificates/create-a-certificate-signing-request/)

1. Launch Keychain Access located in `/Applications/Utilities.`
2. Choose `Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate` from a Certificate Authority.
3. In the Certificate Assistant dialog, enter an email address in the User Email Address field.
4. In the Common Name field, enter a name for the key (for example, Abishek Thangaraj Dev Key).
5. Leave the CA Email Address field empty.
6. Choose `"Saved to disk"`, then click Continue.

[image]

**Step 2:** [Create enterprise distribution certificates](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/create-certificates/create-enterprise-distribution-certificates/)

1. In [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles,](https://developer.apple.com/account) click Certificates in
   the sidebar.
2. On the top left, click the add button (+).
3. Under Software, select “In-House and Ad Hoc”, then click Continue.
4. Follow the instructions to [create a certificate signing request](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/create-certificates/create-a-certificate-signing-request/) .
5. Click Choose File.
6. In the dialog that appears, select the certificate request file (a
   file with a .certSigningRequest file extension), then click Choose.
7. Click Continue.
8. Click Download.
   The certificate file (a file with a .cer file extension) appears in
   your Downloads folder.

To install the certificate in your keychain, double-click the downloaded certificate file. The certificate appears in the My Certificates category in Keychain Access.

**Step 3:** [Register an App ID](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-profiles/create-an-app-store-provisioning-profile/)

1. In [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles,](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list) click Identifiers in the
   sidebar, then click the add button (+) on the top left.
2. Select App IDs from the list of options and click continue.
3. From the options, confirm App ID type is automatically selected,
   then click Continue.
4. Enter a name or description for the App ID in the Description field.
5. To create an explicit App ID, select Explicit App ID and enter the
   app’s bundle ID in the Bundle ID field.
6. The explicit App ID you enter here should match the bundle ID you
   entered in the target’s Summary pane in Xcode.
7. To create a wildcard App ID, select Wildcard App ID and enter a
   bundle ID suffix in the Bundle ID field.
8. Select the corresponding checkboxes to enable the app capabilities
   you want to use.

   The capabilities available to your type of app and
   program membership appear under Capabilities. A checkbox is disabled
   if the technology requires an explicit App ID and you’re creating a
   wildcard App ID, or the technology is enabled by default. Not all
   capabilities are eligible for all platforms.
9. Click Continue, then review the registration information, then click
   Register.

**Step 4:** [Create an App Store provisioning profile](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-profiles/create-an-app-store-provisioning-profile/)

To create a distribution profile for your app in Xcode, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" in your developer account.
2. Click on "Profiles" in the sidebar.
3. Click the add button (+) located at the top left corner.
4. Under Distribution, choose the appropriate App Store distribution profile for your platform:

   - App Store: for iOS, watchOS apps, and App Clips.
   - tvOS App Store: for tvOS apps.
   - Mac App Store: for macOS apps, including those configured with Mac Catalyst.
5. Select the App ID you used for development (matching your bundle ID) from the App ID pop-up menu.
6. If you use automatic signing during development:

   - Choose "XC Wildcard" if it's the only option available.
   - Otherwise, select the Xcode-managed explicit App ID starting with "XC" and containing your bundle ID, or the registered App ID matching your bundle ID.
7. Choose your distribution certificate and click Continue. Note that an App Store provisioning profile contains a single distribution certificate.
8. Enter a profile name and click Generate.
9. Finally, click Download to retrieve your distribution profile.

This process ensures that your app is properly configured for distribution through the App Store or other relevant platforms.
[image]
Then right-click on the provisioning profile file and choose `Open with > XCode.` Profile will automatically be added and will be above screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your extremely thorough and wonderful answer @Abishek Thangaraj (+1). I followed all of your steps exactly, however please see my update at the bottom of my question (up above). When I downloaded the provisioning profile and then open it with XCode, I get a new error: "_Provisioning profile "<redacted>-distribution-profile" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Distribution: <redacted> Holdings LLC (<redacted_team_id>)_". Any ideas what I need to do to fix this or why I would be seeing this? Thanks again so much!

Comment: Hi, I think you select the wrong certificate when creating App Store provisioning profile.

Comment: Unfortunately @Abishek Thangaraj that is not the case, I am 100% sure I selected the cert that I created earlier today (following your instructions). Is `Apple Distribution` the name of the certificate it is looking for? Is it possible I need to name the certificate a certain way? I had named my certificate "<redacted> Holdings LLC" and it is an **iOS Distribution** type certificate. Anything look wrong there?

Comment: Thanks but I can't, but I could chat with you in StackOverflow's chat feature if that helps.

Comment: Kindly check the your certificate is installed in system Keychain or login keychain?. if installed in system keychain please install in  login keychain also.

Comment: Hey!!! It looks like `ios_distribution.cer` is the default name of the certificate you download, and I had already installed one with this name yesterday. When I was clicking it to install the new one about an hour ago, my Mac was seeing that this cert already existed and was failing silently, not alerting me that the new `ios_distribution.cer` cert wasn't being installed. I deleted the old `ios_distribution.cer` and installed the new one from today. It installed, and Xcode removed the error! Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Generated a CSR with macOS's `KeyChain Access` App, it will generate a CSR and pairing private key in the keychain app automatically.

[image]

2. When you uploaded the CSR(certificate signing request file) to Apple Developer Console to create a new certificate, in your case we choose "iOS App Development", we will get a downloadable certificate.

[image]

3. Download and install this certificate. And you can verify this by opening `Keychain Access` App and goto `Certificates` tab. If your installation is successful, you will see a pairing private key with the certificate.

[image]

The rest steps about provision profiles are the same like yours.

Please retry above steps and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks @kakaiikaka (+1) -- I will give this a try, but how would I install this cert on a MacOS CI/CD server? I see Macs have a `security add-trusted-cert` command, would that work? I ask because I'd like to use this cert for local development as well as part of my CI/CD pipeline. Thanks again!

Comment: As you may see from my last image, with a pairing private key, you can right click on this cert and choose "Export XXX" to export it, make sure to use p12 as the format(when asked for a password, you can leave it empty). Then copy to your CI/CD mac server, double click to import the p12 file.