Impossible to create a provisioning profile for my iOS app
I'm trying to create an iOS app with a very specific code signing identity (because the iPads that will download my app use an MDM), but since a code signing identity is specified, Xcode wants me to set the "Code Signing Style" to "Manual" and as a consequence a provisioning profile has to be manually set:

Therefore, I go to my account on https://developer.apple.com and start creating a new profile as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78186591/14522489

I select the App ID I created for this new app and then I get stuck on this step:

I'm stuck because I have created a certificate for iOS App Development, but it doesn't show up in the list and Apple's website tells me that no certificates are available, which makes no sense since I've just created one (by following the instructions on https://developer.apple.com/help/account/create-certificates/create-a-certificate-signing-request/)
Please, can someone explain to me why is it so hard to create a provisioning profile and why Apple Developer won't let me?

I haven't created Developer ID type before. However, I believe you're missing Distribution certificate rather than Development certificate.

A "Developer ID" profile is only for Mac apps that you will be distributing with Apple notarisation.  How are you planning on signing the apps you will distribute to the iPads?  Will you be using a custom app via App Store Connect?

@Paulw11 I do not wish to publish the app on the App Store, as I will plug the iPads to my Mac and use Xcode to transfer the application to them. What else should I use then ? I don't want to use "Ad Hoc" because I cannot list the iPads I will transfer the app to.

@sonle Yes you are right, thank you, but the certificate still doesn't show up, so the problem remains.

If you don't use the App Store, you will need to add the udid of all of the iPads to your developer account and use an ad-hoc build. You will need to replace the build periodically. I strongly suggest you look into custom app distribution via App Store Connect and Apple Business Manager.

@Paulw11 This app is meant to be installed on thousands of iPads so there is absolutely no way I can list them all. Also, what is App Store Connect and Apple Business Manager ?

Apple Business Manager is a free service that your organisation can sign up for. Once you do you get an organisation Id. In App Store Connect you can then set your app to only be available to that organisation. You submit your app for review as usual but once it is approved it does not appear on the App Store. You can use the Apple Business Manager site to "purchase" as many copies of your app as you need. These can then be distributed by your MDM see https://developer.apple.com/custom-apps/

Your other option is to sign up for an enterprise developer program, but that is relatively expensive and complex. Watch this wwdc video to understand your options.

@Paulw11 thank you for this information, unfortunately what I'm trying to do is quite untypical. I want to simulate clicks and taps on the iPads that have this app, and to do this I use xcodebuild test command with a scheme that contains XCTests. Those tests get executed and a pre-defined algorithm starts tapping and clicking around to achieve a specific goal, over the whole iPad. As a consequence, I can't deploy the app like Apple expects developers to do. What complicates everything is the MDM, and I own a certificate controlled by this MDM so as to be allowed despite the restrictions.

The only way an app can be installed on a (non-jailbroken) iOS device is for that app to be signed by Apple or for it to be signed by an enterprise program certificate or for it to be signed with an ad-hoc provisioning profile that includes the device udid. An MDM won't allow apps to be installed.
